# Should the salesforce-crm tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There is a salesforce-crm tag:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-crm

I'm unable to see any specific relation to questions using the tag or realize a meaning and use for the tag. Should it be deleted or can anyone add a meaningful wiki content ?

Comment: Is there actually such a thing as a tag blacklist? The wiki got updated to say not to use it, but it's clearly ignored all the time. It's still a top-4 tag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Definitely should be deleted. It's redundant

Comment: I'm traveling at the moment... Saariko - could you ask in the moderators' chat room how we can have salesforce-crm put on the tag blacklist?

Comment: yes, redundant plus confusing....same goes for apex-code, apex-component.

Comment: Should we look at removing this tag when we edit questions?

Answer (score 4):

I've removed [salesforce-crm](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-crm):

[image: Just the intrinsic tag, not the whole site, please.]

There are now a number of [questions with no tags](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged). Please go over those questions and either edit in the appropriate tag or, if the question has no value, delete.

I've also blacklisted the tag:

[image: The 'Salesforce-crm' tag is not allowed.]

Please let me know if any problems crop up.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I like the Trogdor reference when you remove the tag.