# How do we actually kill this tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[One of our top four tags](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/salesforce-crm/info) has the following description:

> This tag will be removed, do not use it.

It's been that way for years. It's just about the least informative possible tag. And yet, at time of posting, it has more than 40% more tagged questions than `soql` (3077 to 2138), our query language. That's crazy. Do we have a way to definitively kill this tag?

**EDIT**

After looking at one of [@Peter](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/498/peter)'s posts on the tag, I realized that there is a problem with removing the tag entirely: some posts have only that tag. Since every post needs at least one tag, what do we do with such posts?

**UPDATE 7/29**

We're down to 2891 posts for `salesforce-crm` versus 2184 for `soql`. Headed in the right direction!

**UPDATE 12/22**

The `salesforce-crm` tag is out of the top four! And it's about to be passed for fifth as well! We've now managed to go over five months without any new posts being allowed to keep this tag. The actual tag deletion seems to have stalled, but we're heading in the right direction.

Top 8 tags as of today:

```
tag               |  posts
=========================
apex              |  15997
visualforce       |  10715
trigger           |   3825
marketing-cloud   |   2624
salesforce-crm    |   2578
soql              |   2518
unit-test         |   2318
javascript        |   2183
```

Comment: Maybe the mods can delete tags. I've hit Matt up, let's see. On a side note, I've been rejecting a lot of new tags without description or improvement recently. I see more and more people are chasing that badge without actually providing any benefits. We have to be carefully monitoring these things

Comment: As the the post with only that one tag, there is always some other topic that applies. There have got to be a small number with only that tag, and with a little effort an alternative can be had, I'm sure.

Comment: I just mean if we delete the tag, an automatic process has to be capable of retagging, no?

Comment: The tricky bit with an automated process is that we don't want to end up with another tag on a really high proportion of posts again that isn't informative.

Comment: You only really *need* to retag when it's the *only* tag.

Comment: Just an observation I feel like I am seeing increased, inaccurate, use of the salesforce-communites and salesforce2salesforce tags now...

Comment: @Girbot You're not wrong. The fight against lazy tagging rages on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2446/2995), a Community Manager has deleted this tag for us. It has been blacklisted as an "intrinsic tag" and cannot be resurrected.

Comment: For anyone who wants to help out in re-tagging all of the questions that were previously only tagged with `salesforce-crm`, they are now tagged as `untagged`. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged?sort=newest&pageSize=15

Comment: I've started helping out with the re-tagging, made me realise that we had some more tags required and tag descriptions to do.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is one for a SE employee... unless I'm missing something I can't find a way to kill it! Will chase it up.

Comment: The way I see it there are two separate problem here. 1) The tag is more popular than much more useful tags. The posts that are already tagged with it should be untagged. 2) People keep using it. Getting it deleted should help with both, hopefully!

Comment: I do try and remove that tag when editing posts but it being deleted would be helpful as it would mean it won't keep showing up.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: And once killed, how to prevent it from respawning?

Comment: Make sure the killing blow was acid or fire damage.

Comment: Yes, hydra may rear another head. But at least it should be one of our least popular tags again. I wish there were a logical tag synonym.

Comment: Also...what about the `sfdc` [tag](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sfdc). I know it isn't a top tag by any stretch, but equally pointless.

Comment: An SE employee will ask you to form consensus on meta that the tag should be removed, then will remove it for you. You will need to manually retag any questions that are left without tags.

Comment: @ArtOfCode What constitutes consensus? It doesn't look like anyone objects so far, but do we need to conduct some sort of yea/nay polling?

Comment: @AdrianLarson "no objections" is probably enough, to be honest.

Comment: You should probably post this as an answer haha. I just have one more question. What happens with the manual retagging process? Does it fill up a queue or something? Will it be obvious how to find the posts that need such retagging?

Comment: @Art I think it's fair to say we have no objections since the post has been open for almost two weeks and the reaction has been all agreement.

Comment: @ArtOfCode `<bump />`. Do you know any more about who that SE employee would be or if the wheels are in motion?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I don't, I'm afraid. One of your mods needs to talk to a CM, which I haven't seen going on in the Teachers' Lounge, but may have happened via other means.

Comment: Is this stalled out? It seemed like we were so very close a month ago. /bump

Comment: Gah... my bad! I'll raise it in the Teacher's Lounge

Comment: @LaceySnr Any luck? Would love to close this one out! Sorry to nag, and thanks for all your help!

Comment: @AdrianLarson No, it's good you brought it up again. I did ask in the teacher's lounge but got nothing. Will try again.

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to curate this tag specifically by only removing the tag from posts created within the last 24 hours. I think it's really important we not bury the front page too far and snow it under with cruft. I started on July 13 and our newest post with the tag is still July 12.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean. do you mind explaining? specifically about not burying the front page.

Comment: I think I get it now...because of the "active" filter. I hadn't even thought of that...although I hardly ever visit that view...does anyone? Or do people mostly visit due to google search results. Either way, I'll hold off for the time being. :-)

Comment: Right, I think it will harm usability for a lot of us if we mass update posts to remove the tag. I use the home page with the active filter almost exclusively. It makes it easy to see what's getting the most recent interest. What view do you use @Peter?

Comment: I typically look at "recent", or am looking at a specific tag (like Lightning Components lately).

Comment: It is sort of a bummer that just adding/removing a tag pushes a question into "active". Kind of makes an unnecessary obstacle to curation.

Comment: Totally agree with you there. Retagging doesn't really make it any more relevant, per se.

Comment: I mainly use the Active filter too so I can see that would be a pain for me and a lot of the community if we start getting all the old questions and answers surfacing again.

Comment: When old questions are getting pushed back into active by the 'community' account I take the chance to remove the tag as they are already in the Active filter list, but that would take forever to deal with the backlog of old questions with it.

Comment: Spotted a couple today after reading this, I'll keep an eye out too :)

Comment: Whoops, forgot about edits removing tags showing up on the 'active' page. I'll try to spread out my effort a bit more (hell, if all of us combined only untag/retag 10 per day, we'll be done by the end of September this year).

Comment: @DerekF We may have a Community Manager stepping in soon to nuke this tag. Stay tuned. :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson good to hear! I guess I'll shift my focus to retagging the questions that only have the `salesforce-crm` tag.

Comment: @DerekF **[Only 275 of those!](http://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/edit/622563)**